# Azure App Service (free trial) with Azure Hybrid Connections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-hybrid-connections

I have a simple question. Are Azure Hybrid Connections available with an Azure App Service free trial subscription plan? I'm able to add hybrid connections within my Azure App service; however, they are not being recognized when I try to connect to my on prem SQL Servers. Note, I have tried using both the FQDN and the IP address.

Thanks,
Snawwz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after I posted this question, I found the answer. It appears that the Azure App Service free tier plan supports Hybrid connections.

[image]

Comment: The page: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections says that Hybrid connections are available only on Basic, Standard, Premium, and Isolated pricing SKUs.